# exit from a shell script after spawning threads

Tags: multithreading, shell, unix

I have a simple script say test.sh something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 
do
 ssh BOX someCommand&
done
exit 0
```

When I run the script, it spawns 6 processes and outputs the result on screen, but after its done it just waits there. I need to do ctrl+c to come out. The problem is I cannot call test.sh multiple times in other script, since it would just wait for the first call to exit forever. Any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Nitpicking your terminology; background processes created with `&` are not threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually does exit immediately. Your problem is that the script is exiting *too* soon, before the output gets printed to the screen. So the output overwrites your prompt, and when you hit ctrl-c it redraws the prompt.

Try adding a "`wait`" command right before the exit - then the script won't exit until all the ssh processes are done.

By "output overwrites your prompt" i mean:

- First: the script exits
- Second: your prompt prints - "user@computer$ " or whatever.
- Third: all the output of the ssh commands prints
- At the end you're left with the cursor on a blank line without a prompt on it, which is what made you think it didn't exit. Then when you hit ctrl-c the prompt prints again.

Comment: thnx for the answer. That worked. Can you clarify on "output overwrites your prompt," aint it suppose to print output on the prompt .. why does it overwrite it .. I guess for the same reason I dont completely understand how the wait solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

i tried something similar and the script exited properly

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3 
do
    ssh id@box "ls -l" &
done

echo "i am done"
```

Only difference is i use bash shell

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

I have done this sort of work, and the output can get rather muddled. How long are you waiting? Are you sure it isn't really done.

Add  `banner done` before the exit 0 and then you'll be certain that it is really hung.

The other possiblity is that something about `someCommand` is not really finishing. If it is a script that you control, add an `echo "someCommand on ${HOST} is finished"` to be sure each one is finishing.